# AlamoFire not working with tvOS / CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, tvos

AlamoFire doesn't seem to be working with CocoaPods for tvOS - here is the info and the error message.

```
pod --version - 0.39.0
```

Podfile:

```
platform :tvos, '9.0'
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'tvOS'
```

Terminal:

```
> pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `Alamofire` from `https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git`, branch `tvOS`

[!] Error installing Alamofire
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git /var/folders/w_/90_3ly_d1xl6t0gfg9xmr52w0000gn/T/d20151111-1787-1j3pdql --single-branch --depth 1 --branch tvOS

Cloning into '/var/folders/w_/90_3ly_d1xl6t0gfg9xmr52w0000gn/T/d20151111-1787-1j3pdql'...
warning: Could not find remote branch tvOS to clone.
fatal: Remote branch tvOS not found in upstream origin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no longer need to use a specific branch, apparently the *tvOS* branch already has been merged into master, and it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :tvos, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

works for me